# How to sort mysql coloumn that has data in Bytes KB MB GB?

Tags: mysql, search, sorting

I have a table with column 'size' that has file sizes in diff units like '10 Kb', '50 MB', '1 GB'.
The problem is when I try to sort, it returns 1 GB row at first.

How to solve this prob without changing old data ???

Any help is much appreciated... Thanks.

Comment: I would have rather stored the size in bytes and only format as human-readable when outputting.

Comment: Seems to me that the long term solution has to be changing those values. One field should store only one measure, say Kb, and then do the conversion to Gb etc. when needed. Otherwise working with data data will always be a a bit messy.

Comment: I changed all data to bytes and using same approach for all of my applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really either convert all data into a common unit (say bytes) or add a column which contains a "unit of measure" and keep the size column itself numeric.

Having said that, the following should work on data in that ends with either GB/MB/KB or B.

```
select size
  from t
 order 
    by case when size like '%GB' then power(1024, 3) * substr(size, 1, length(size) - 2)
            when size like '%MB' then power(1024, 2) * substr(size, 1, length(size) - 2)
            when size like '%KB' then power(1024, 1) * substr(size, 1, length(size) - 2)
            when size like '%B'  then                  substr(size, 1, length(size) - 1)
        end desc;


+-------+------------+
| size  | bytes      |
+-------+------------+
| 1GB   | 1073741824 |
| 10MB  | 10485760   |
| 100KB | 102400     |
| 1000B | 1000       |
+-------+------------+
```

Comment: +1 for a real good approach. Probably, each insert and update SQLs should also auto-fill the `bytes` column without changing the application code.

Comment: @Nishant, hehe... I hope you meant my first sentence? Otherwise I don't want the upvote, because that order by is !#¤%& :)

Comment: yep. I meant the new column thing. It's a good patch without touching the app code if you can make older units converted and each update and insert takes care of it. well deserve a +1. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have size contain actual values and format them somewhere higher up (in your view).

Or you could make it ugly and write a function that takes a human readable value and returns the actual integer and then SORT BY foo(size). Did I mention it's ugly?

EDIT: Since you want to keep old data, here's another ugly solution:

SORT BY REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(size, ' GB', '000 MB'), ' MB', '000 kB'), ' GB', '000')

(I'm on fire!)

Disclamer: You REALLY SHOULD change the data, it's the only way to keep it clean.

Comment: +!,, @Sunny really you want to store data in bytes, then it will be really easy to format elsewhere.

Comment: I made a mistake before. I stored data in diff. formats. U suggesting me to change 100+ thousands of rows?

Comment: It's a simple change. Write a simple script, thoroughly test it on a small but representative data set and keep it working over night.