# Rails how to order data based on "disk size" value which is stored as string?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am created Rails 5 application with MySql as backend. 
 I have "Server" model with "disk_size" field and disk_size field is varchar and values stored like "10 GB", "512 MB". I want result with order data by disk_size field in ascending order like "512 MB", "10 GB".

Comment: this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605627/how-to-sort-mysql-coloumn-that-has-data-in-bytes-kb-mb-gb.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will generate a lot of overflow in calculating the sizes from the strings. Plus you can't use sql to order these which would be way faster.

A better way would store them in bytes so it will be an integer which can be sorted.

If you then want to print out the size you can use the `number_to_human_size` helper. See the [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_human_size)

E.g.

```
irb(main):003:0> size = 10_000_000
=> 10000000
irb(main):004:0> number_to_human_size(size)
=> "10 MB"
```

EDIT:

According to Andrey Deineko, this was not an answer.

So here's the ruby way (without a very very very long sql query to solve this):

Build a class named "FileSize" for example (You can put that in `app/models/`):

```
class FileSize
  include Comparable

  UNITS = {
    "MB" => 1_000_000,
    "GB" => 1_000_000_000,
    # ...
  }

  def initialize(str)
    @str = str
  end

  def to_bytes
    count, unit = @str.split(" ")
    if UNITS.key?(unit)
      count.to_i * UNITS[unit]
    else
      raise "Don't know unit #{unit.inspect}, please specify."
    end
  end

  def <=>(other)
    to_bytes <=> other.to_bytes
  end

  def inspect
    @str
  end

  def to_s
    @str
  end
end
```

complete the `UNITS` constant with all the units you have.

If you're using ActiveRecord you can overwrite your getter of your model:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  def disk_size
    FileSize.new(super)
  end
end
```

So you can do this:

```
MyModel.where(something: "is").sort_by(&:disk_size)
```

Comment: while it is a good recommendation which i totally agree with, it is not an answer to the question - the column is already a String

Comment: How is that not an answer?

Comment: You suggested an alternative which involves db schema change, not a solution for current set up (despite the fact that this way it would make more sense). What you should have done, is provide a solution to current problem **and** then suggest a better way. This is how this site work. You can not answer a question saying "throw away all you have and start over like this" - there might be circumstances which, for example, do not allow OP to change the db schema. How would your answer qualify in such case?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Is that an answer to you?